# Java RMI best way to access object by multiple clients

Tags: java, rmi

i am new to **Java RMI** and i do not know exactly how to solve this.

Multiple Clients are using my app, i have remote object and i know, that Two Clients cannot use this object at the same time. What should i do to make this object accessable for many clients without errors?

Is making methods `synchronized` enough for solving my problem? Is there anything else i have to take care of? I don't really understand, **please enlighten me**

Other posts didn't really gave me informations i need.

Answer (score 1):

> I know, that Two Clients cannot use this object at the same time.

No you don't. RMI isn't single-threaded.

> What should i do to make this object accessable for many clients without errors?

Nothing, except make your remote methods thread-safe as necessary.

> Is making methods synchronized enough for solving my problem?

Only you can answer that. Only you know the concurrency requirements of your application.

> Is there anything else i have to take care of?

Only you can know that.

> I don't really understand, please enlighten me

Nobody can enlighten you about this. Only you can know your own concurrence requirements.

> Other posts didn't really gave me informations i need.

You won't find it in other posts. You will only find it by analyzing your own design.